# In what situations does new return the same address twice?

Tags: c++, templates

Why does the following not compile? It says "error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token".

```
template<typename K, typename V>
struct cmpf {
const K& r;
V& visitor;

cmpf(const K& _r, V& _visitor) : r(_r), visitor(_visitor) {}

template<typename T>
void operator()(T& l) {

    if (r.type == a_type(T)) {
        return l == r.get<T>(); // DOES NOT WORK
    } else return false;
}
};
```

Why does the compiler bot understand this? get() is a function defined in type K with a template argument. In this case, I want to use T as the argument, but the compiler does not recognize this. When I use the following instead, it works (but it's not right, since get is a template function):

```
    return l == r.get();
```

Comment: What does your code have to do with `new`? Also what is the type of `K`, and what is the definition of that type? You have very little code.

Comment: And the actual error message instead of "does not work" might help.

Comment: In any case, I predict it should be `return l == r.template get<T>();`, but I don't like posting prediction answers.

Comment: Oh, and to answer the title question: `new` may return the same address twice when the memory from the first has been reclaimed via `delete` between the two `new` expressions, or anytime on broken implementations.

Comment: `new(nothrow)` will also return the same address twice if it's still out of memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
return l == r.template get<T>();
```

Read this FAQ for more information: [What is the `->template`, `.template` and `::template` syntax about?](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#templateprefix)

Comment: @glowcoder : Yep, he beat me to it, I spent too much time looking up the FAQ URL. :-P

Comment: thank you, and thank you for the link! up until now, I've just been learning templates by example; this is a good FAQ.

Comment: @user451963 : It's a good FAQ for C++03, but keep in mind that much of it is outdated and/or incorrect for C++0x.