# Error compiling C++ program

Tags: c++, compilation

I get this error while compiling:
 error: aggregate 'X x' has incomplete type and cannot be defined

I have three classes in 6 different files(header file + 3 implementation files). when I try to compile all these classes with a main, It gives me the above error. I am not including any header file in other header files, I am doing that in implementation files. So, I think its not a case of "cross reference". I am not sure what is the problem with my code can anyone help me in that?

Thanks

Comment: Well, can you show us the class definitions? I suspect you have something like: `struct X { X x; } `.

Comment: where X is another class

Comment: @ManPreet: Then that class isn't defined where you're trying to use it, make sure the header for it as been included. Much simpler would be to include your abridged header file code, though. Make sure you have proper include guards, and no circular uses.

Comment: That solved most of my errors Just one more to go                    error: field 'isbn_ord' has incomplete type

Comment: I have three class x,y, and z. class x{char man[10];} class y{char woman[10];} class z{x x;}

Comment: @Man: I can't help you any further until you show us your code.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out the problem. I forgot to include one of the header file.

Comment: OKay. Well I'd be lying if I said I didn't want some rep. :P I'll post my comment as an answer.

Comment: @GMan: You got like 62k rep already!! But nice answer, +1 from me :)

Comment: @Als: Haha, I know! Let's say it's to balance me [giving answers away](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480221/in-what-situations-does-new-return-the-same-address-twice). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow, that class isn't being defined when it needs to be.

Firstly, make sure the header has actually been included. Further, make sure you have include guards, and that you don't have circular includes and recursive definitions. Aside from that, without the code we cannot give specifics.